# Is it possible to use Android NDK without NativeActivity?

Tags: android, android-ndk

[Documentation of Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts#main_components) somewhat implies, that I *can*, not *must* use `NativeActivity`. I would need to do so if I'm going to create a fully-native app.:

> Manifest: If you are writing an app with no Java component to it, you must declare the NativeActivity class in the manifest. See Use the native_activity.h interface for more detail on how to do this.

However I would like to have a normal Java activity with having an `android_main` function in C++. Is this possible? Currently if I inherit my activity from anything other than `NativeActivity`, my C++ `android_main` is  not called at all.

Comment: Not sure if you found: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/android-mk/hello-jni Prior to NativeActivity, Android developers had to write their own Activity to call into JNI (and probably prefer).

Comment: @MorrisonChang I see, so in case I want to setup a draw loop of my application, I would need to initiate it on Java side with calls to JNI on every frame, compared to fully C++ drawing loop?

Comment: The NDK samples there are on the older side. There still needs to be an Activity to pass in UI and system events to the C/C++ code, however if you may want to look at: https://developer.android.com/games/agdk/game-activity where to my understanding they are trying to hide some of the Android-ness away from the C/C++ devs. Do realize that since Android is [open source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/NativeActivity.java) the code is there if you wish to get into the weeds.